# Render is not updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I want to delete a user, I would like to display a confirmation pop-up. So when I press the delete button, I would like my pop-up to appear. What I do is that I have a pop up that I render according to a poster variable. If it is true then I display if it is false I do not display. Logically when I press the delete button I'm supposed to display my pop up so I modify the variable and put it in true but my pop up is not displayed

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import AuthentificationService from "../../api/AuthentificationService"
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import Modal from "../Modal/Modal"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 360,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
}));

export default function CheckboxList(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let deleteIt = false;
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([0]);

    const handleToggle = value => () => {
        const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
        const newChecked = [...checked];

        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(value);
        } else {
            newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
        }

        setChecked(newChecked);

    };

    const deleteUser = value => () => {
        AuthentificationService.deleteUser(value.id)
            .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);

        }) .catch((error) => {

        })
    }

    const confirmationDeleteUser = value => () => {
        deleteIt = true;
    }

    return (
        <List className={classes.root}>
            {props.response.map( test => {

                if (props.response.length <= 1) {

                } else {
                    return (
                        <ListItem key={test} role={undefined} dense button onClick={handleToggle(test)}>
                            <ListItemText primary={`${test.email}`}/>
                            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete" onClick={confirmationDeleteUser(test)}>
                                    <DeleteIcon />
                                    <div>
                                        {deleteIt === false ?  "" : <Modal title="Confirmation" message="hey"/>}
                                    </div>
                                </IconButton>
                            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        </ListItem>
                    );
                }
            })}
        </List>
    );
}
```

when my deleteIt variable is equal to true so I want to display my popup. Why doesn't it work?
What am I not understanding?

Comment: Your deleteIt variable isn´t part of the state, so it wont render after you change it, change ```let deleteIt = false``` to  ```const [deleteIt, setDeleteIt] = React.useState(false);``` and alter it using the setDeleteIt function

Answer (score 3):

React will only re-render if a value that is a prop or part of the component's state changes. In your case, the `deleteIt` variable is not a state variable, so even if you change it with `confirmationDeleteUser`, your component won't re-render to trigger the popup.

Try to define your variable with `useState` instead, like this:

```js
const [deleteIt, setDeleteIt] = useState(false);
```

And change your code in `confirmationDeleteUser` to change `deleteIt` like this:

```js
setDeleteIt(true);
```

That should get things heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are using a stateless component. so, you will never see a change in the front with this type of component.

You should use the stateful component instead, and set the values to change in the state property, and change them using the setState() function.

see [State in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)